# Verification of Sample Space of the below problem.

Tags: probability

In a bag there are 2 fair coins(one side head and other tails)  and 1 coin with heads on both side. **we randomly pick one coin from bag  and toss it 2 times**.

Then

> is the below sample space correct?

```
SampleSpace = { (F1, HH),(F1, HT), (F1, TH), (F1, TT),
                (F2, HH),(F2, HT), (F2, TH), (F2, TT),
                (U1, HH) 
             }
```

Fi means ith fair coin and Ui means ith unfair coin

> what is the probability of getting head on second toss?

Below is my solutoin is it correct?

```
SampleSpace = { (F1, HH),(F1, HT), (F1, TH), (F1, TT),
                (F2, HH),(F2, HT), (F2, TH), (F2, TT),
                (U1, HH) 
             }
FavourableEvents = { (F1, HH), (F1, TH),
                     (F2, HH), (F2, TH),
                     (U1, HH) 
                  }
    required_probability = |FavourableEvents|
                           -------------------
                              |SampleSpace|
where|X| means size of the set.
                        = 5/9
```

> if it is given that first result of coin is head and we are being asked what is the probability that second toss results in head?

is my solution correct?

```
newSampleSpace = { (F1, HH),(F1, HT),
                   (F2, HH),(F2, HT),
                   (U1, HH) 
                }
    FavourableEvents = {  (F1, HH),
                          (F2, HH),
                          (U1, HH)
                       }

     required_probability = 3/5
```

Comment: Yes, it is correct. But remember that $(U_1,H)$ is twice as probable as other sample space elements. Also note that the sample space is subjective -- I could, for example, just chose $S=\{H,T\}$.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Thank you for answering. But i have edited the ques please have a look at it again.

Comment: You need to clarify which event are you making the sample space for. If the event is tossing a randomly chosen coin twice, then your current sample space is okay (except a small typo in the second line where it should be $F_2$). But if you are making the sample space for just the second toss, the earlier sample space was  fine too

Comment: @ShubhamJohri corrected the typo and highlighted the event.and you got it right its the first one i wanted to ask.
but i have more questions on this question(around  4 or 5)  do i edit the question or ask a new question?

Comment: You can ask a new question and in its body place a link to this question.

Comment: it says i can post only every 40 min.(i need to wait 4*40 = 160 mins) . i am forced to edit the ques. is there any workaround?